# How can work with a long unformatted string in python to extract information based on found index?

Tags: python, regex

I have the following text (which has been extract from the mail body using Exchangelib)

```
The following task were executed for department A . PLEASE STORED AS FOLLOWS 

“Task done with APO”

APO Sent / A department  Stored 
VIA LOCAL MARKET
ACCOUNT 67805670-11
```

with the following basic code I can print the index where the pattern is found.

```
body = receivedbody
result = body.find("ACCOUNT")
print(result)
```

How can I search for `ACCOUNT` and print the number `67805670-11` which follow the found pattern?

Basically what I wanted to do is to interact with the body received using Exchangelib, maybe there is some library or internal method in Exchangelib which help me with that.

Comment: simply with regex `ACCOUNT\s*(\d+-\d+)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for this you need to use regular expression or re

```
    text="""The following task were executed for department A . PLEASE 
        STORED AS FOLLOWS
       
         “Task done with APO”
        
         APO Sent / A department  Stored
         VIA LOCAL MARKET
         ACCOUNT 67805670-11"""
    
    import re
    pattern = r"[\d]*-[\d]*"
    re.findall(pattern=pattern, string=text)

    ['67805670-11']
```

So what's happening here:

`re.findall(pattern, string)` uses the pattern to identify the portion of your text that this pattern.
The pattern `r"[\d]*-[\d]*"` looks for a string that has multiple digits followed by a dash followed by more digits. I didn't specify how long the preceding and succeeding digit length is but one certainly can.

you can specify a pattern that will include the existence of letters separated by a space from the account number:

```
pattern = r"[\w]*\s*[\d]*-[\d]*"
re.findall(pattern=pattern, string=text)

['ACCOUNT 67805670-11']
```

you can easily assign the output to a namespace:

```
output  = re.findall(pattern=pattern, string=text)
if output != []:
    print(f"The account number is {output[0].split(' ')[1]}")
else:
    print("no account number found")


The account number is 67805670-11
```

Comment: Just change ```text.findall``` for  ```re.findall```

Comment: namespace example does't work, python complain because the object ```output``` which is a list, does not have ```split``` attribute

Comment: @Sallyerik, Thanks for troubleshooting. Done. Fixed both. needed to reference `output[0]`

Answer (score 1):

If the account number is at the end of the string, this method also works. Note: it would take some extra work if the account number is *not* at the end of the string.

```
s = \
"""
The following task were executed for department A . PLEASE STORED AS FOLLOWS 

“Task done with APO”

APO Sent / A department  Stored 
VIA LOCAL MARKET
ACCOUNT 67805670-11
"""

print(s[s.index("ACCOUNT") + len("ACCOUNT") + 1:].rstrip())
```

The index() function returns the index of the beginning of "ACCOUNT", and then we get to the account number by adding the length of "ACCOUNT" and the space, then strip off any potential newlines off the right side of the end of the string.

Comment: Thanks, works fine but unfortunately the account number can be anywhere within the body. I will go for the option of regex as per @hussam answer.